# Pug `2.0.0 beta 5` with express on node 6+

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Today, as 90% free days I wanted to test some "technology" and I found the `heroku` with `nodeJS` will be nice topic.

The tutorial went with `ejs` templates, and I wanted to change them to jade (not convert, just use jade), so I added `pug` inside the project.

Look on my `index.js` please (`node 6.2.0`)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// const RouteService = require('./server/services/RouteService');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
// RouteService.registerRoutes(app);
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('/pages/index', { title: 'Hey Hey Hey!', message: 'Yo Yo'});
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

So this is mainly the heroku template.`index.js` is `./index.js` in main folder, the `index.jade` is `./views/pages/index.jade`.

Error (locally with `node index.js` and in heroku (same command)) is

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/pages/index" in views directory "/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/views"
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/index.js:16:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/daniel/Pulpit/crystal-fan-prototype/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

I feel that I have very trivial issue that I can't recognize, thanks in advice!

(and this error is ofc after GET'ting the `/` on `localhost:5000`, server starts listening correctly)

Comment: Shouldn't your view file be named index.pug instead of index.jade?

Comment: Indeed. And `/pages/index` should be `pages/index`. Thanks for pointing it out man!

Comment: Please consider deleting this question as it was due to a simple typographical error.